# The action could not be found for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, routes, initialization

Having gone through my code I have a separate problem from my original question and rather than writing a new question. I will leave the old part at the bottom of this and post the new problem here. I do this because they are closely related.

New:

Im getting an error message saying

```
Unknown action

The action 'response' could not be found for CrawlerController
```

I'll keep it simple but the code for model, controller and routes are below in the previous question.

A basic run down is response is a def within CrawlerController as is add_Request.
The routes are matched as such:

```
  match  "/requests/new" => "crawler#add_Request"
  match 'requests/:id' => 'crawler#response'
```

Here is controller code as per user request:

```
class CrawlerController < ApplicationController
def add_Request
@request = Request.new(params[:request])

respond_to do |format|
  if @request.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@request, :notice => 'Request was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @request, :status => :created, :location => @request }

  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @request.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def response
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js { render :json => @request }
  end
end

def show
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @request }
    format.json{
      render :json => @request.to_json
    }
  end
end
 end
```

Comment: Apologies in advance if my naming conventions are all over the place. I'm still new at this

Comment: SO this was fixed because of an extra end at a block. Anyone any ideas on why it never stopes select * from results where id=1 when I say   127.0.0.1:8080/requests/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please recheck code of controller as I can see it

```
class CrawlerController < ApplicationController
  def add_Request
    @request = Request.new(params[:request])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@request, :notice => 'Request was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @request, :status => :created, :location => @request }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @request.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    def response
      @request = Request.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render :@request.to_json}
    end
  end
```

so one end is missing an your `response` action is defined inside `add_Request`

Comment: I've actually removed requests as a resource because apparently this opens it up to al rest services. I'd rather define my own routes

Comment: could you please remove old part and repost code from your controller?

Comment: Oh my christ........ I think i'll stick with java next project. if that was a { I would have caught it. Thanks a bunch mate. now I just gotta find out why the requests arent going in with a post request.

Comment: Switching to java because it uses curly braces. Very clever move.

Comment: @overtone - I laughed a bit at your curly brace comment, then noticed that's why mine wasn't working either *face palm*.